# Unable to login to admin panel of Joomla even after password change from Mysql

Tags: joomla

I forgot the password of my Joomla Site and decided to change it from Mysql what I do when I forget. So the change was made in jos_users table password with selection of md5.

Now when I am trying to login, it is not working with error as below:

Username and password do not match

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Go to Joomla and ask this question. You will get faster response and have it asked in a more appropriate place. https://forum.joomla.org/

Comment: Trying hard to get option to post question there after login. Can't see yet.

Comment: You can't do that.  Did you read the how to recover your password information on the Joomla docs wiki?  Joomla does not support md5 hash.  Also state what version of joomla.

Comment: see documentation here, there are multiple methods to recover the password: https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_recover_or_reset_your_admin_password%3F

Answer (score 0):

It is not a solution but a check:

Always look into your joomla configuration file to see which database it is connected with. If you have multiple databases in phpadmin you may easily confused which is actually connected.

I was changing password in wrong config file.

Comment: If this is "not a solution" please do not post it as one.  You may add it as a comment, or include it in your question body.  If your question could not be reproduced or was caused by an error that no one had access to, then this question is off-topic and may be closed/deleted.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to register as a new user and the use the database to give that user Superadmistrator privileges. Or copy the password from that user with the correct hashing over to your Superadministrator with unknown password.

Default registration link is example.com/index.php?option=com_users&view=registration